# How to remove fault class in ACM ACR template

Tags: overleaf, acm

I posted this question before but still unable to resolve the issue,
[How to remove overlapping text on ACM ACR template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/693786/how-to-remove-overlapping-text-on-acm-acr-template)

please help  i tried to add space manually after every heading to avoid overlapping \vspace{10pt} %  but still i am not able to add space manually for references heading

I am using this ACR latex template on Overleaf

https://www.sigapp.org/acr.html

All submissions must be in ACM formats. Please use the ACR template: MS Word and LaTex.

but there is overlapping on pdf text.

here is the code of the template:

```
% This is "sig-alternate.tex" V2.1 April 2013
% This file should be compiled with V2.5 of "sig-alternate.cls" May 2012
%
% This example file demonstrates the use of the 'sig-alternate.cls'
% V2.5 LaTeX2e document class file. It is for those submitting
% articles to ACM Conference Proceedings WHO DO NOT WISH TO
% STRICTLY ADHERE TO THE SIGS (PUBS-BOARD-ENDORSED) STYLE.
% The 'sig-alternate.cls' file will produce a similar-looking,
% albeit, 'tighter' paper resulting in, invariably, fewer pages.
%
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% This .tex file (and associated .cls V2.5) produces:
%       1) The Permission Statement
%       2) The Conference (location) Info information
%       3) The Copyright Line with ACM data
%       4) NO page numbers
%
% as against the acm_proc_article-sp.cls file which
% DOES NOT produce 1) thru' 3) above.
%
% Using 'sig-alternate.cls' you have control, however, from within
% the source .tex file, over both the CopyrightYear
% (defaulted to 200X) and the ACM Copyright Data
% (defaulted to X-XXXXX-XX-X/XX/XX).
% e.g.
% \CopyrightYear{2007} will cause 2007 to appear in the copyright line.
% \crdata{0-12345-67-8/90/12} will cause 0-12345-67-8/90/12 to appear in the copyright line.
%
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% This .tex source is an example which *does* use
% the .bib file (from which the .bbl file % is produced).
% REMEMBER HOWEVER: After having produced the .bbl file,
% and prior to final submission, you *NEED* to 'insert'
% your .bbl file into your source .tex file so as to provide
% ONE 'self-contained' source file.
%
% ================= IF YOU HAVE QUESTIONS =======================
% Questions regarding the SIGS styles, SIGS policies and
% procedures, Conferences etc. should be sent to
% Adrienne Griscti (griscti@acm.org)
%
% Technical questions _only_ to
% Gerald Murray (murray@hq.acm.org)
% ===============================================================
%
% For tracking purposes - this is V2.0 - May 2012

\documentclass{sig-alternate-05-2015}
  \pdfpagewidth=8.5truein
  \pdfpageheight=11truein

\begin{document}

% Copyright
\setcopyright{acmcopyright}

\title{ACM ACR Template\titlenote{(Produces the permission block, and
copyright information). For use with
SIG-ALTERNATE.CLS. Supported by ACM.}}
\subtitle{[Extended Abstract]
\titlenote{A full version of this paper is available as
\textit{Author's Guide to Preparing ACM SIG Proceedings Using
\LaTeX$2_\epsilon$\ and BibTeX} at
\texttt{www.acm.org/eaddress.htm}}}
%
% You need the command \numberofauthors to handle the 'placement
% and alignment' of the authors beneath the title.
%
% For aesthetic reasons, we recommend 'three authors at a time'
% i.e. three 'name/affiliation blocks' be placed beneath the title.
%
% NOTE: You are NOT restricted in how many 'rows' of
% "name/affiliations" may appear. We just ask that you restrict
% the number of 'columns' to three.
%
% Because of the available 'opening page real-estate'
% we ask you to refrain from putting more than six authors
% (two rows with three columns) beneath the article title.
% More than six makes the first-page appear very cluttered indeed.
%
% Use the \alignauthor commands to handle the names
% and affiliations for an 'aesthetic maximum' of six authors.
% Add names, affiliations, addresses for
% the seventh etc. author(s) as the argument for the
% \additionalauthors command.
% These 'additional authors' will be output/set for you
% without further effort on your part as the last section in
% the body of your article BEFORE References or any Appendices.

\numberofauthors{8} %  in this sample file, there are a *total*
% of EIGHT authors. SIX appear on the 'first-page' (for formatting
% reasons) and the remaining two appear in the \additionalauthors section.
%
\author{
% You can go ahead and credit any number of authors here,
% e.g. one 'row of three' or two rows (consisting of one row of three
% and a second row of one, two or three).
%
% The command \alignauthor (no curly braces needed) should
% precede each author name, affiliation/snail-mail address and
% e-mail address. Additionally, tag each line of
% affiliation/address with \affaddr, and tag the
% e-mail address with \email.
%
% 1st. author
\alignauthor
zzz\\
       \affaddr{zz}\\
       \affaddr{zz}\\
       \affaddr{zz}\\
       \email{zz}
% 2nd. author
\alignauthor
xx\\
       \affaddr{xx}\\
       \affaddr{xx}\\
       \affaddr{xx}\\
       \email{xx}
% 3rd. author
\alignauthor Mbbb \\
       \affaddr{xx}\\
       \affaddr{W}\\
       \affaddr{M}\\
       \email{m}
%\and  % use '\and' if you need 'another row' of author names
% 4th. author
%\alignauthor Lawrence P. Leipuner\\
%       \affaddr{Brookhaven Laboratories}\\
 %      \affaddr{Brookhaven National Lab}\\
  %     \affaddr{P.O. Box 5000}\\
   %    \email{lleipuner@researchlabs.org}
% 5th. author
%\alignauthor Sean Fogarty\\
 %      \affaddr{NASA Ames Research Center}\\
  %     \affaddr{Moffett Field}\\
   %    \affaddr{California 94035}\\
    %   \email{fogartys@amesres.org}
% 6th. author
%\alignauthor Charles Palmer\\
 %      \affaddr{Palmer Research Laboratories}\\
 %      \affaddr{8600 Datapoint Drive}\\
  %     \affaddr{San Antonio, Texas 78229}\\
   %    \email{cpalmer@prl.com}
}
% There's nothing stopping you putting the seventh, eighth, etc.
% author on the opening page (as the 'third row') but we ask,
% for aesthetic reasons that you place these 'additional authors'
% in the \additional authors block, viz.
\additionalauthors{Additional authors: John Smith (The Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Group,
email: {\texttt{jsmith@affiliation.org}}) and Julius P.~Kumquat
(The Kumquat Consortium, email: {\texttt{jpkumquat@consortium.net}}).}
\date{30 July 1999}
% Just remember to make sure that the TOTAL number of authors
% is the number that will appear on the first page PLUS the
% number that will appear in the \additionalauthors section.

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
abccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
\end{abstract}


%
% The code below should be generated by the tool at
% http://dl.acm.org/ccs.cfm
% Please copy and paste the code instead of the example below. 
%
\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010553.10010562</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Embedded systems</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010575.10010755</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Redundancy</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>300</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010553.10010554</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Robotics</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>100</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10003033.10003083.10003095</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Networks~Network reliability</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>100</concept_significance>
 </concept>
</ccs2012>  
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Computer systems organization~Embedded systems}
\ccsdesc[300]{Computer systems organization~Redundancy}
\ccsdesc{Computer systems organization~Robotics}
\ccsdesc[100]{Networks~Network reliability}


%
% End generated code
%

%
%  Use this command to print the description
%
\printccsdesc

% We no longer use \terms command
%\terms{Theory}

%\keywords{ACM proceedings; \LaTeX; text tagging}
\keywords{ab,b,c}
\section{Introduction}
than the threshold ξ in this task. Since the same task requester
may choose the same individual in different tasks for a while, an
edge may represent multiple interactions between two individuals.
The out-degree and in-degree of the vi can be used to measure the
influence of individual i in the community. Influence reflects the
reliability of the reputation evaluated by the individual i, rather
than his own reputation. Section 3.1 describes the role of interaction
graph.than the threshold ξ in this task. Since the same task requester
may choose the same individual in different tasks for a while, an
edge may represent multiple interactions between two individuals.
The out-degree and in-degree of the vi can be used to measure the
influence of individual i in the community. Influence reflects the
reliability of the reputation evaluated by the individual i, rather
than his own reputation. Section 3.1 describes the role of interaction
graph.than the threshold ξ in this task. Since the same task requester
may choose the same individual in different tasks for a while, an
edge may represent multiple interactions between two individuals.
The out-degree and in-degree of the vi can be used to measure the
influence of individual i in the community. Influence reflects the
reliability of the reputation evaluated by the individual i, rather
than his own reputation. Section 3.1 describes the role of interaction
graph.than the threshold ξ in this task. Since the same task requester
may choose the same individual in different tasks for a while, an
edge may represent multiple interactions between two individuals.
The out-degree and in-degree of the vi can be used to measure the
influence of individual i in the community. Influence reflects the
reliability of the reputation evaluated by the individual i, rather
than his own reputation. Section 3.1 describes the role of interaction
graph.


\section{Conclusions}
This paragraph will end the body of this sample document.
Remember that you might still have Acknowledgments or
Appendices; brief samples of these
follow.  There is still the Bibliography to deal with; and
we will make a disclaimer about that here: with the exception
of the reference to the \LaTeX\ book, the citations in
this paper are to articles which have nothing to
do with the present subject and are used as
examples only.
%\end{document}  % This is where a 'short' article might terminate

%ACKNOWLEDGMENTS are optional
\section{Acknowledgments}
This section is optional; it is a location for you
to acknowledge grants, funding, editing assistance and
what have you.  In the present case, for example, the
authors would like to thank Gerald Murray of ACM for
his help in codifying this \textit{Author's Guide}
and the \textbf{.cls} and \textbf{.tex} files that it describes.

%
% The following two commands are all you need in the
% initial runs of your .tex file to
% produce the bibliography for the citations in your paper.
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{sigproc}  % sigproc.bib is the name of the Bibliography in this case

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This template is obsolete and no longer supported.  The supported version is `acmart`, see the documentation at [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acmart)

Comment: where to dowload the supported versin.. any idea

Comment: It should be a part of your TeX distribution.  The latest official version is at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acmart

Comment: i created the overleaf project of the previous template.. for this latest official version, there is no .tex file given,,or if i need to copy some files to the previous version.. i am not able to understand which files i need to copy to the previous version

Comment: Look at samples files for the template